# Download Latest File in a SharePoint Folder

Tags: c#, filestream, httpwebresponse

My current code downloads a SharePoint file from an absolute URL of the file and writes to local.

I want to change it to use the folder URL instead and downloads file in the folder base on some filter.

Can it be done?

Below is my current code snippet:

```
string fullFilePath = DownloadSPFile("http://MySharePointSite.com/sites/Collection1/Folder1/File1.docx/");

public static string DownloadSPFile(string urlPath)
{
    string serverTempdocPath = "";

    try
    {
        var request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(urlPath);
        var credentials = new NetworkCredential("username", "password", "domain");

        request.Credentials = credentials;
        request.Timeout = 20000;
        request.AllowWriteStreamBuffering = false;

        using (HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse())
        {
            using (Stream stream = response.GetResponseStream())
            {
                serverTempdocPath = Path.Combine(AppConfig.EmailSaveFilePath + "_DOWNLOADED.eml");

                using (FileStream fs = new FileStream(serverTempdocPath, FileMode.Create))
                {
                    byte[] read = new byte[256];
                    int count = stream.Read(read, 0, read.Length);
                    while (count > 0)
                    {
                        fs.Write(read, 0, count);
                        count = stream.Read(read, 0, read.Length);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        AppLogger.LogError(ex, "");
        throw ex;
    }
    return serverTempDocPath;
}
```

Comment: Dont remember the exact api, but theres one where given a folder path you can List the files in the folder. Then form the Individual file URLs you are  interested in. Vaguely recall it was SharePoint List Service.

Comment: @PrateekShrivastava I will Google and see if I can find it!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your sharepoint site enables sharepoint rest api, you can get the details very easy.

Get list of files

```
url: http://site url/_api/web/GetFolderByServerRelativeUrl('/Folder Name')/Files
method: GET
headers:
    Authorization: "Bearer " + accessToken
    accept: "application/json;odata=verbose" or "application/atom+xml"
```

and pass query for that

```
"?filter=$top=1&$orderby=Created desc"
```

[More information](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/sp-add-ins/working-with-folders-and-files-with-rest)

Answer (score 0):

Has you try to format your urlPath ?

like: 
`string urlPath = "path/to/folder/";
string fileFilter = "Cat.png";
string finalPath= String.format("{0}{1}", urlPath, fileFilter);`
(Or anything like this)

(Hope I understand your question and I was able to help you ^^)

Comment: Thanks, you get where I am coming from. As the file name will not be known, I will be required to get the `latest file` in the folder. So it is kind of a headache.

Comment: Erf, kind of tricky.
You can probably get time information thanks to [WebUtility.HtmlDecode](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.webutility.htmldecode?view=netframework-4.8#System_Net_WebUtility_HtmlDecode_System_String_), but I think you will have to do yourself your filter and iterate on all existing files in your folder :/
But if you work with the SharePoint REST service, you can probably find pre-existing filter to help you to download the newest file.

Comment: Look at [this](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/35796.sharepoint-2013-using-rest-api-for-selecting-filtering-sorting-and-pagination-in-sharepoint-list.aspx) website. They talk about listing document based on their modification time.
Hope it will help you :)